# R parallel rocessing with for loop in function

Tags: r, for-loop, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I am building a parallel processing loop which has a for loop nestled inside.  for simplicity sake I am only including one line of code within the function and for loop but in reality there are about 1000 lines of code. In this small example, I am building a grid for which I would like to iterate over all the rows in `AllDatasets` plugging in the values of the column named "a" where I just want to transform them from a list into a numeric number and return that value.

When I iterate over the rows in `AllDatasets` I would like to return the value of that rows iteration.

Currently my code returns `20  20  20  20  20  20`.  I would like my code to return a vector of

`20 
 21 
 22 
 23 
 24 
 25`
Essentially, I want my function to pass the value of column `a` to a new variable (`PredictValue`) in order to use that value to run some additional calculations before it moves onto the next now in the `AllDatasets`dataset.
Thank you for your help!

Here is my code:

```
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
start.time <- Sys.time()
cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", detectCores()))
AllDatasets <- expand.grid(b = 21, c = 21, d = 21, e = 21, a = 20:25)

my_sum <- function(temp, list) 
{
  AllDatasets <- expand.grid(b = 21, c = 21, d = 21, e = 21, a = 20:25)
  for(j in seq_len(nrow(AllDatasets)))
  {
    PredictValue <- as.numeric(as.character(unlist(AllDatasets$a[j])))
    return(PredictValue)
  }
}
cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", detectCores()))
result <- parApply(cl = cl,      
               X = AllDatasets,    
               FUN = my_sum, 
               MARGIN = 1, 
               list = list)  
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken
stopCluster(cl)

result
```

Comment: Your `return(PredictValue)` should be outside the for loop. You also will need to iteratively build `PredictValue` before returning it. So, `PredictValue <- NULL` and `PredictValue <- c(PredictValue, ...)` (but this is a bad way to do it in R). (If you'd like more input, could you clean up `my_sum` a bit? You pass arguments `temp` and `list` to it, but don't use them.)

Comment: Thanks for the help so far.  Can you explain a bit more the part you mentioned about `PredictValue <- c(PredictValue, ...)`?  temp and list will be used further down the code.  I just left them in for now as I do not believe they have an impact?

Comment: Your current code, `PredictValue <- as.numeric(as.character(unlist(AllDatasets$a[j])))`, will only save the last `jth` element. You're probably thinking that you can `return(...)` iteratively but `return` does not work that way. Rather you must generate the full output data you want and return once. `PredictValue <- c(PredictValue, ...)` saves the previous value of `PredictValue` and adds an element(s) to it. (I'm not 100% sure what output you're looking for. This is one reason it's helpful to explicitly show desired output rather than a synopsis of it.)

Comment: Ok, I think I understand.  I updated the question above to show what I am looking for.  Essentially, I want to pass the the value from column a of  AllDatasets to convert it into a number that I can use for other calculations.  But for this example, I just want to restate the numbers for the values in the rows of column a from data set AllDatasets